# App Check from Firebase in Flutter doesn't work

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-app-check

I'm trying to use App Check from Firebase with Flutter (on Android only for now), but the documentation is just terrible and I don't understand the errors I get when I try to access a Firebase service with an App Check token.

I run my app on my personal Android device through the terminal using the following command: `flutter run --no-sound-null-safety`.

I want to access data on Firebase Storage with that app. I have enforced App Check on that feature, I have also enabled SafetyNet for my app and I have created a debug token entitled "tests" that I don't even know how to use.

Here is the error I get:

[image: My error]

Here is my `main()` function:

```dart
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_app_check/firebase_app_check.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate();

  // ... not related code

  runApp(MyWidget())
}
```

Here is my `build.gradle` in `/android/app/`:

```
// ...

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-safetynet:16.0.0-beta03'
}
```

Here is my `MainActivity.kt` in `/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/my_app/`:

```kotlin
// the package

import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp
import com.google.firebase.appcheck.FirebaseAppCheck
import com.google.firebase.appcheck.safetynet.SafetyNetAppCheckProviderFactory

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(/*context=*/ this);
        val firebaseAppCheck = FirebaseAppCheck.getInstance()
        firebaseAppCheck.installAppCheckProviderFactory(SafetyNetAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance())
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```

Please help me guys, nothing works now.

Comment: Did you later solve this ?

Comment: I've never solved this. I stopped using App Check.

Comment: i later solve this both iOS and Android is working perfect

Comment: How ? Would it work for me now ?

Comment: i dont no, but it work for me.

Answer (score 0):

in my main.dart

```
  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate();
```

Here is my build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-debug:16.0.0-beta06'
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
 import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
    import android.os.Bundle
    import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp
    import com.google.firebase.appcheck.FirebaseAppCheck;
    import com.google.firebase.appcheck.debug.DebugAppCheckProviderFactory
    
    
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(/*context=*/this)
        val firebaseAppCheck = FirebaseAppCheck.getInstance()
        firebaseAppCheck.installAppCheckProviderFactory(
            DebugAppCheckProviderFactory.getInstance()
        )
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```